# A subgroup made of elements from all the cosets.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $H\le G$ such that $m:=[G:H]$ is finite. How can I *construct* (perhaps by some iterative routine?) a subgroup $M:=\{g_i, i=1,\dots,m\}\le G$ such that distinct $g$'s are elements of distinct left (right) cosets of $H$ in $G$? Surely there is no such an $M$ for every $G$ and $H$, but I'm interested in the construction of such an $M$ when $G$ and $H$ allow its existence.

Comment: Such an $M$ is called a *complement* of $H$; not every subgroup has a complement, but perhaps the technical term will let you do a preliminary search to see if an algorithm exists. In general, it is not necessarily easy to even determine whether a complement exists. See, e.g., [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5528/when-does-a-subgroup-h-of-a-group-g-have-a-complement-in-g)

Comment: For techniques for proving the existence of complements, see Theorem of Gaschütz.